# Python dataframe partial string replacement

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a dataset with dates in the form 01JAN2020 I am looking to convert these to 01-01-2020 They could occur in any column in the dataframe. The solution I have is to export it to CSV and do it with SED which works but is very slow. SED command for reference is:

```
conversions="sed -Ei -e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(JAN)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-01-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(FEB)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-02-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(MAR)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-03-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(APR)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-04-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(MAY)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-05-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(JUN)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-06-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(JUL)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-07-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(AUG)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-08-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(SEP)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-09-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(OCT)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-10-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(NOV)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-11-\\3/g' "
conversions=conversions+"-e 's/(,[0-9][0-9])(DEC)([0-9]{4},)/\\1-12-\\3/g' "+filename
subprocess.run(conversions, shell=True)
```

I was hoping to do this directly in the python program most likely with re but can't get the partial substitution correct. Once I get the date format done I should be able to manage the timestamp(01JAN2020:00:00:00) myself. Running this over multiple files and ultimately about 1TB of data so runtime is important.

Edit for additional details:

The columns containing the dates and timestamps are unknown and different for each frame that will run through the process.

There may be null values mixed among the dates which should be ignored.

The change should be made in place as column order is important.

Perhaps a 2 step solution.
Step 1 determines all columns where all non-null values match the regex described above.
Then a second step to convert the matching format for the matching columns.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, just try to minimize the number of times you read your file (12 times with your sed command!). Also, it is likely not necessary to use pandas as the read_csv and to_datetime operations are probably costly as well. If your sed approach worked you could try to do it in one pass. Something like:

```
months = {'JAN': '01', 'FEB': '02', 'MAR': '03', 'APR': '04', 'MAY': '05', 'JUN': '06', 'JUL': '07', 'AUG': '08', 'SEP': '09', 'OCT': '10', 'NOV': '11', 'DEC': '12'}
with open('in.csv', 'r') as f_in, open('out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in.readlines():
        f_out.write(re.sub(r'(?<=,\d\d)('+'|'.join(months)+')(?=\d\d\d\d,)', lambda m: months.get(m.group()), line))
```

If you need to read you data as dataframe anyway, then you can use one of these, depending on whether you prefer to have `string` or `datetime` type:

```
# fix as string
import re
months = {'JAN': '01', 'FEB': '02', 'MAR': '03', 'APR': '04', 'MAY': '05', 'JUN': '06', 'JUL': '07', 'AUG': '08', 'SEP': '09', 'OCT': '10', 'NOV': '11', 'DEC': '12'}
re_months = re.compile(r'(?<=\d\d)('+'|'.join(months)+')(?=\d\d\d\d)')

def fix_date_str(e):
    if type(e) != str:
        return e
    return re_months.sub(lambda m: months.get(m.group()), e)

df.applymap(fix_date_str)
```

```
# fix as datetime
def fix_date2_datetime(e):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(e, format='%d%b%Y')
    except ValueError:
        return e
df.applymap(fix_date_datetime)
```

Comment: This worked and provided a significant performance boost over the SED method I was using. 
I still think there is more efficiency to be gained and less file IO(NFS Drive) to do this directly in the dataframe, or possibly some clever use of pipes that are beyond my limited python experience. 
I need to load the dataset into a dataframe anyway as the frame in question is actually an amalgamation of multiple CSV files, and I generate a database load statement based on the contents of the dataframe.

Comment: @RG I believe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519463/python-dataframe-partial-string-replacement/#68523880) will solve your issue and boost performance.

Comment: If you need to load the data anyway, then have a look at the proposed alternatives. It should keep the other types unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, as I don't have any dataset of yours, I have created my own dataset based on your examples.
**DataFrame:**

```
            p                  q
0       TI688 09MAR2078 00:08:00
1   01JAN2020                 77
2     73dhi38  08NOV199700:00:00
3       jdkdn          03DEC2089
4   01JAN2020               _£^&
5       783i3                NaN
6  90YINM7832                NaN
```

Now what we are doing is making dictionary of name of month and values of month like this:

```
months = {"JAN":"01","FEB":"02","MAR":"03","APR":"04","MAY":"05","JUN":"06","JUL":"07","AUG":"08","SEP":"09","OCT":"10","NOV":"11","DEC":"12"}
```

We have this dictionary now, if we find month name then we can replace it with number easily. So, we have to make regex to find string that followed `01JAN2020` pattern. Here's the code to find that:

```
pat = r"(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<month>[A-Z]{3})(?P<year>\d+)"
```

Now, we found the month we can replace it with this:

```
repl = lambda m: f"{m.group('day')}-{months[m.group('month')]}-{m.group('year')}"
```

Don't change anything in day and year but in month replace it according to `months` dictionary. We are almost done, we have to apply these things in `DataFrame` like this:

```
df=df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(pat,repl,regex=True))
```

Finally the output is:

```
            p                   q
0       TI688 09-03-2078 00:08:00
1  01-01-2020                  77
2     73dhi38  08-11-199700:00:00
3       jdkdn          03-12-2089
4  01-01-2020                _£^&
5       783i3                 NaN
6  90YINM7832                 NaN
```

## Complete Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"p":["jdkdn","01JAN2020","73dhi38","jdkdn","01JAN2020","783i3","90YINM7832"],"q":["09MAR2078","77","08NOV199700:00:00","03DEC2089","_£^&",np.nan,np.nan]})

months = {"JAN":"01","FEB":"02","MAR":"03","APR":"04","MAY":"05","JUN":"06","JUL":"07","AUG":"08","SEP":"09","OCT":"10","NOV":"11","DEC":"12"}

pat = r"(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<month>[A-Z]{3})(?P<year>\d+)"
repl = lambda m: f"{m.group('day')}-{months[m.group('month')]}-{m.group('year')}"

df=df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(pat,repl,regex=True))

print(df)
```

## And for your issue here's the code to solve it, I believe you have `list of files`:

```
import pandas as pd

months = {"JAN":"01","FEB":"02","MAR":"03","APR":"04","MAY":"05","JUN":"06","JUL":"07","AUG":"08","SEP":"09","OCT":"10","NOV":"11","DEC":"12"}

pat = r"(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<month>[A-Z]{3})(?P<year>\d+)"
repl = lambda m: f"{m.group('day')}-{months[m.group('month')]}-{m.group('year')}"

#files=os.listdir() #You can use this as well.

for file in files:
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    df=df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(pat,repl,regex=True))
    df.to_csv(file) #If you want to save in other file then that file name.
```

This should work faster then you expected.

**Edit :**
This will not work as expected if datatype of some places is `int64`  or `float64`. So, we may have to convert dataframe to string by doing this:

```
df=df.applymap(str)
```

Place before applying replace. Now it will work as expected. But I have found one problem. It will convert `Nan` and `None` also to string. Which may lead to problem but if we face any problem because of string `nan` then we can do this:

```
df.replace("nan",np.nan,inplace=True)
```

Now `int64` and `float64` is changed into string, so previous code will work perfectly.

## Code:

```
df=df.applymap(str)
#df.replace("nan",np.nan,inplace=True) #Optional if we need it then only use it
df=df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(pat,repl,regex=True))
```

Comment: @RG Check the performance and notify me. If it is also slow then I have another idea to boost the performance.

Comment: This may work with some tweaks but for now it is aborting as some of the fields are of type int64 and float64. In the morning I may try to play with it and apply to only fields where dtype=object